# Etimología de "piragua"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

La palabra "piragua" parece ser de esas cuya etimología parece obvia en un principio: una embarcación, vehículo capaz de navegar por el agua, que contenga la misma palabra "agua" en su nombre no puede ser casualidad. ¿O sí? Resulta que según el diccionario, la palabra *[piragua](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T8SSLQG)* se originó en el caribe, y más concretamente, según [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?piragua), viene del taíno. No da más información, más que mencionar que los taínos fueron los habitantes precolombinos de las Bahamas, las Antillas Mayores y el norte de las Antillas Menores.

La conclusión con tan poca información parece ser que el hecho de que se llame *piragua* no es más que una curiosa coincidencia. ¿Es esto así? ¿Existe más información al respecto que pueda confirmar esto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según todas las fuentes habituales, *piragua* viene de *piraua*, que significa canoa hecha con un tronco ahuecado y es una palabra de la lengua [caribe insular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_kalh%C3%ADphona) o iñeri, "lengua arawak del grupo caribeño hablada en las Antillas Menores y relacionada filogenéticamente con el taíno de las Antillas Mayores" (el caribe propiamente dicho no tiene relación con esta lengua, pese a su nombre). La palabra aparece por primera vez en castellano [alrededor de 1530](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pirogue), pasando al francés como *pirogue* en 1660 y de ahí [al inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirogue).

Curiosamente hay en Puerto Rico un tipo de helado que se llama *[piragua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piragua_(food))*, pero sin relación con la canoa (según Wikipedia, viene de *pirámide* y *agua*, ya que es un raspado helado con forma de pirámide o cono).

Comment: Es probable que el paso de *piraua* a *piragua* se haya visto influido por la palabra *agua*, aunque lo cierto es que en castellano tenderíamos a pronunciar una g ahí, por lo que parece una evolución fonéticamente coherente.